# AngularJS, <select>. The `ng-click` on the <option> is not work

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I use AngularJS. I bind data on the select options. I bind a click function on each option. When I click the option, the `clickFun` does not work.

This is my code:

```
<style>
    .bigDiv {
        width: 500px;
        height: 500px;
        background-color: gray;
        margin: 34px auto;
    }
</style>


 <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
 <div class="bigDiv">
     <select name="xxx" id="">
         <option ng-repeat="item in Array" value="" ng-click="clickOptionFun($index)">{{item.name}}</option>
     </select>
 </div>

  <script src="angular.js"></script>
 <script>
      var app  = angular.module('app',[]);
     app.controller('controller',['$scope', function ($scope) {
         $scope.Array = [
             {name: "one"},
             {name: "two"},
             {name: "three"},
             {name: "four"},
         ];

         $scope.clickOptionFun = function (index) {
             console.log(index);
         }
     }])
 </script>
```

I set a breakpoint at the  clickOptionFun. It seems the funcion does not implement. I can't look any log information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a ng-model for the ng-change, you can pass the selected object like this,

```
 <select name="xxx" id="" ng-model="selected"
    ng-options="item as item.name for item in Array"
    ng-change="clickOptionFun(selected)">
 </select>
```

**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/RYICuiSMUFvErnTi3ZFW?p=preview)**

Answer (score 0):

Try remove `[]`

```
var app  = angular.module('app');

app.controller('controller', function ($scope) {
    $scope.Array = [
         {name: "one"},
         {name: "two"},
         {name: "three"},
         {name: "four"},
    ];

    $scope.clickOptionFun = function (index) {
         console.log(index);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

probably you should use ng-change instead of ng-click, ng-options to fill the options

```
<select name="xxx" ng-options="item as item.name for item in Array"
    ng-change="clickOptionFun(item)">
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all there is no clic event for select,you can use ng-change and ng-model

```
    <style>
        .bigDiv {
            width: 500px;
            height: 500px;
            background-color: gray;
            margin: 34px auto;
        }
    </style>


     <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
     <div class="bigDiv">
         <select name="xxx" id="">
             <option ng-repeat="item in Array" value=""
 ng-change="clickOptionFun(item)">{{item.name}}</option>
         </select>
     </div>

      <script src="angular.js"></script>
     <script>
          var app  = angular.module('app',[]);
         app.controller('controller',['$scope', function ($scope) {
             $scope.Array = [
                 {name: "one"},
                 {name: "two"},
                 {name: "three"},
                 {name: "four"},
             ];

             $scope.clickOptionFun = function (name) {
                 console.log(name);

             }
         }])
     </script>
```

You can also use option instead of ng-repeat

Comment: <select ng-model="selectedName"  ng-change="clickOptionFun(item)"
ng-options="item.name for item in Array"></select>

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-change event for `<select>`. There is no click event for .